# Unity 2D tilemap collider2d won't get removed when a tile is removed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a map that has a tile map collider 2D on a brick and a composite. It runs perfectly on a game test. When I build and run the player, it drops a bomb. It destroys the tile and tile is set to null, but the Tile map collider doesn't get updated, and the player can't step on the place.

It had a brick on it. I tried disabling the composite and adding again, but didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share some code; specifically, [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Unity itself. A new version fixed it.